# Problems with looping when using redirect in route of React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, react-component

There is component that detect browser and return message about unsupported browser or return redirect. The part of code of this component is bellow:

```
detectIE() {
    const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    const msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    console.log(msie);
    if (msie > 0) {
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }
    return false;
}

render() {
    if (this.detectIE()) {
        return (
            <FullPageError
                title={''}
                image={<BntIconWrapper icon={<SvgPageErrorGeneric />} defaultColor={true} />}
                explanation={''}
                userOptions={''}
            ></FullPageError>
        );
    }
    return <Redirect to="/login" />;
}
```

This component (`<Route component={checkBrowser} />`) rendering in root component as bellow:

```
            <Switch>
                <Route component={checkBrowser} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={checkLogin} />
                <Route exact path="/signin-oidc" component={checkSignInOidc} />
                <Route path="/error-page" component={ErrorPageContainer} />
                <Route path="/authorizeExternal" component={AuthorizeExternal} />
                <Route path="/" component={checkDarklyProjects} />
                <Route path="**" component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
```

The core of problem is that when `detectIE()` return false and component return `<Redirect to="/login" />` occurs the looping. I think the looping occurs because in the `<Route component={checkBrowser} />` property `path` is absent. But this is done so that the component responds to any URL.
How render other controls after checking browser?

Answer (score 1):

The looping happens because when you redirect it the base component (the one with the switch) gets re-mounted and re-rendered every time.
My recommendation is to not redirect the user to login since your component `checkBrowser` only checks the browser (and not if the user is logged in) as well as moving your `checkBrowser` to the outside of the switch.

My Recomendation for your code

```
render() {
    if (this.detectIE()) {
        return <Redirect to={"/error-page"} />;
    }
    // don't render anything to the DOM if its not an IE browser
    return null;
}
```

```
<checkBrowser/>
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/login" component={checkLogin} />
   <Route exact path="/signin-oidc" component={checkSignInOidc} />
   <Route path="/error-page" component={ErrorPageContainer} />
   <Route path="/authorizeExternal" component={AuthorizeExternal} />
   <Route path="/" component={checkDarklyProjects} />
   <Route path="**" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `<Route component={checkBrowser} />` outside `<Switch></Switch>`